# Chrome resizing CSS background url image

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome 3.0.196.2 and I noticed that for some reason the #main div's background is shrunk a tad bit, even though it should not be. It tests fine in every other browser but chrome.

Anyone know why?

Link to site: [link text](http://www.ipalaces.org/weird/)

Even have a screen shot: [link text](http://skipall.com/2va.png)
Notice the green on the right side is cut off, as well as things not lining up.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
        #main {
            border: 10px solid black;
            height: 300px;
            width: 1000px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding-top: 50px;
            background: #AAA url("http://www.ipalaces.org/weird/mainbg.gif"); 
        }
        #picture {
            border-top: 1px solid #EEE; 
            border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
            height: 100px;
            width: 1000px;

        }
    </STYLE>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <TITLE>Imperial Palaces</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>


<DIV id="main">
    <IMG id="picture" src="http://www.ipalaces.org/weird/mainbg.gif" alt="picture">
</DIV>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: is this straight from your code? because you're missing a semi-colon at the end of the #main definition, it's not going to solve your problem, never the less, semi-colons are important!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working OK on Chrome 2: http://skipall.com/2vb.jpg
Remember that Chrome 3 is still in beta, it's *possible* this is just a bug (I'm not sure, of course).

Answer (score 0):

To debug, I think I'd zero-out the paddings and borders - check for differences, then try substituting the IMG for DIV tag to check if it's the container or IMG at fault.  Maybe even chuck in a couple of outline properties to see exactly what's going on:

```
#main {
  padding: 0;
}
#picture {
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  border-width: 1px 0;
}
/* and later... */
#main, #picture {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```