# How to prevent Chrome from resizing background images?

Tags: css, google-chrome, background

I have a css background:

```
background:url(img/bg.png) center top no-repeat white
```

It works fine in FF, Safari, and Opera, but Chrome resizes it. The image is 2000px wide, so that it works on all screen resolutions (except those wider than 2000px of course). However when scrunched in Chrome, it looks weird and throws off the design.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your browser on a zoom level other than 100%? I don't think chrome usually "scrunches" images.

Comment: Looks like its a bug which is not fixed yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237570/chrome-resizing-css-background-url-image

Comment: I updated Chrome from v16 to v18 and it still compresses the width of the image to match the screen (scrunches) instead of letting the extra width expand out, like all the other browsers. I guess it must be a bug - I can't believe I'll have to redesign my webpage because of a bug in Chrome. =/

Comment: Finally figured it out. In Chrome, you have to manually specify the background size when arranging, or it will fill the page with it.

Comment: Just in case one needs a sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7660978/851045

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + 0 should help you out there.

Comment: I'm not sure what zooming would have to do with background stretching, but this has no effect - it's already at 100% zoom and the issue is with the background, not the entire page.